# Does Spring MVC support versioning of static assets (css, js and images )

Tags: caching, web-applications, spring-mvc

Does Spring MVC support versioning of static assets (css, js and images )
by appending the last-modified-date to the asset file names which effectively serves,
caches, and invalidates the assets automatically ?

Rails supports this by using the asset_tag helpers.

I want to add the last-modified-date attribute of a file as a query parameter to serve static assets from the server,
so that if I modify the static files (css, js, images) I do not have to modify my code and cache invalidation can happen automatically.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check [the spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources), section `17.15.6 Configuring Serving of Resources`

Comment: For anyone looking for a working link: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources